# Проверка столкновений по горизонтали и вертикали

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вообщем я создаю 2D платформер на Unity. Я хочу создать свою физику для игрока, ну т.e. не использовать RigidBody2d. И я столкнулся с проблемой. Есть некий объект, в моем случае квадрат и нужно проверить:

1. Есть ли объекты справа/слева/сверху/снизу от куба, при этом не обязательно столкновения, они могут находиться на каком-то расстоянии.
2. Сталкивается ли куб справа/слева/сверху/снизу с каким-либо объектом. Обязательно делать проверку, как показано на рисунке, не заходя за линию.

Нужно использовать что-то вроде Physics2d.overlap и что-то дальше, но как именно непонятно. Прошу дать мне код с подробными пояснениями что и как устроено.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здесь не бюро фрилансеров, писать код с нуля по вашему требованию никто не будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может создать 4 дочерних Empty Object с коллайдерами с разными тэгами. Если второй объект коснулся верхнего объекта с тэгом, например "up", то...

Answer (score 0):

У Unity есть серия уроков создания кастомной 2d физики. [Вот вам ссылка](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/intro-and-session-goals?playlist=17093) на первый из них. Весь код всегда есть под видео, так же можно включить субтитры и их автоматический перевод на русский - он выходит довольно неплохо.